# Sign in with apple feature on ios 13

Tags: apple-id, ios

Apple provides developers to add a `SignInWith apple button` in the ios apps.Does Apple also provides the `SignUpWith apple` button too?

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand.  What exactly is the problem you're facing or question you'd like answered?

Comment: Please *edit* your question to describe in more detail what you want to accomplish and for what you need a login.

Comment: @nohillside I actually think I figured out what the OP is asking about and I have an answer ready.  If you can please take this off hold, I can add my answer.

Comment: I think the button you are referring to may be an example provided by Apple. It’s apples recommended way to display the button following their design UI guide. You have the freedom but restrictions of creating any button you want, you just need to follow the design UI guide here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/buttons/. Also visit iCloud.com on an iOS device... then select use different ID. You can get a sense for how Apple is redirecting users to an option to create an ID.

Comment: @fsb have a go then!

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Developer Documentation addresses this question.  In their [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/) for Sign In with Apple they it states:

> To help people set up an account and sign in, it's best to use the familiar buttons that Apple provides for Sign In with Apple. **When you use the system-provided API to create a Sign In with Apple button**, you get:
>
> - A button that's guaranteed to use an Apple-approved title, font, color, and style
> - Assurance that the button's contents maintain ideal proportions as you change its style
> - Automatic translation of the button's title into the language that's set for the device
> - Support for configuring the button's corner radius to match the style of your UI

There's several examples of buttons designs to fit the look of your app.  You have to use Xcode 11, of course, to get access to this API.

[Here's a short tutorial](https://developerinsider.co/ios-13-how-to-integrate-sign-in-with-apple-in-your-application/) that indicates how to add this feature to your own app.